# Rails: How to combine multiple ActiveRecord associations to a single collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like the following:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :group_projects
end

class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :group_projects

  has_many :time_entries
end

class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

So, `project.time_entries` returns an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` of time_entries belonging to that project.

What I want is a list of all time_entries associated to all projects associated with a particular group as a single collection without having to do something like:

```
TimeEntry.where(["project_id IN (?)", @group.projects.map{|p| p.id } ])
```

PS: Using Rails 4.0.0 | ruby 2.0.0

Comment: What's wrong with passing mapped projects to your query? I doubt there's any built in helpers to help accomplish this otherwise.

Comment: @zeantsoi Tried doing that:

    time_entries = group.projects.map{|p| p.time_entries }

I can flatten that into a single array, but that's all it is - an array - so I can use any ActiveRecord methods on it (eg: .where etc). What I'm after is an ActiveRecord relation/collection of all the time_entries on which I can apply ActiveRecord methods

Comment: Understood. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the edge docs on [*subset conditions*](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions), you can pass an array to the conditions hash of a `where()` query. This will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, rather than an array of objects:

```
TimeEntry.where(project_id: @group.projects(&:id))
```

Note the use of the mapping shorthand (the part with the ampersand). It's an alternative and (perhaps) more readable method for returning an array of a single attribute on multiple objects:

```
@group.projects.map{|p| p.id} == @group.projects(&:id)
```

Comment: Thanks @zeantsoi, this is how I was doing things in the beginning! :) I was trying to rationalise the queries to reduce the sql load time. As it turns out it was something else that was adding to the load. Things are a lot better now.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to zeantsoi answer, you can also use:

```
TimeEntry.where(project_id: @group.project_ids)
```

`@group.project_ids` will return an array of all the ids for that group.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that was possible at the time this question was posted, but right now `has_many :through` seems like an obvious and semantic choice for this task:

```
# Group
has_many :time_entries, through: projects
```

And then you can do:

```
@group.time_entries
```